# Self-updating Java jar

Tags: java, jar

I want to create a self-updating jar.

I've got the first part down: I download the most up to date version. I'd like to delete the current version, though, and that's where I'm stuck. I do the updating at the very end, and I'd like to delete the current jar.

I've tried the File.delete() and the File.deleteOnExit() methods to no avail. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make the new jar in such a way that it will delete the old jar upon execution?

Comment: I think the above is what you need.  Have a separate updater jar which you run to update the main jar.  It downloads the main jar, replaces it, then launches the new one.  Basically one jar updates the other.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in Java Web Start? It allows you to update jars to latest versions. See http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml

Comment: Have you considered using Java WebStart. It would handle the download and make sure the application is up-to-date for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java web start is a good choice for that. A more original method would be to have a very limited core application that relies on other jars that you can upgrade from the core app.